# c++ priority queue with custom comparator operator overloading

Tags: c++

why cannot I overload the comparator operator in the same struct?

I get this error when overloading the operator in the same struct. however, defining the operator in a separate struct works
https://ideone.com/VVHb1L

```
 
struct myC {
    int i;
    myC(int x){
        this -> i = x;
    }
    // this is syntactically wrong
    // bool operator()(myC &a, myC &b) {
    //  return a.i < b.i;
    // }
 
    bool operator()(myC &b) {
        return this ->i < b.i;
    }
};


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    priority_queue<myC, vector<myC>, myC> q;
    q.push(myC(10));
    q.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: based on inputs from @Homer512, `operator()` is not a comparator operator. Its a function call operator.

Comment: You aren't overloading the comparator operator but the function call operator. The signature should look like this: `bool operator<(const myC& b) const { … }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there, you missed a default constructor. And the operator should have const reference parameters. Demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/9qMReoGLR
I added some small notes to further improve your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
//using namespace std; <== do not use using namespace

struct myC 
{
    int i;

    // a default constructor is needed
    myC() :
        i{0}
    {
    }

    // constructors with one argument should almost always be explicit
    explicit myC(int x) 
    {
        this->i = x;
    }

    // the arguments must be const references
    // the operator should not be able to change them
    bool operator()(const myC& lhs, const myC& rhs) 
    {
        return lhs.i < rhs.i;
    }

};

int main() 
{
    std::priority_queue<myC, std::vector<myC>, myC> q;
    
    //q.push(myC(10));
    q.emplace(20); // use inplace construction of myC
    q.emplace(10); 
    q.emplace(30); 

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        std::cout << q.top().i << " ";
        q.pop();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there any reason you use emplace? is it an optimization ? i see that a plain push works too.

Comment: Yes push will work too, but it can result in an extra copy. With emplace the memory where an object can "live" is already allocated by the underlying container, emplace will then construct the object in that memory (also see : placement new)

Answer (score 8):

If you're going to do the overload in the same struct, you normally overload `operator<` instead of `operator()`. And of course you need to make it `const`-correct.

```cpp
struct myC {
    int i;
    myC(int x){
        this -> i = x;
    }
 
    bool operator<(myC const &b) const {
        return this ->i < b.i;
    }
};
```

When you overload `operator<`, that'll be used by default--you don't need to specify a comparator parameter:

```cpp
priority_queue<myC, vector<myC>> q;
```

Comment: This implies there is a natural order to myC objects, which is rarely the case. A properly named comparison struct/lambda is almost always correct.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: it does imply that there's a natural ordering--but if the ordering isn't natural to that struct/class, then it probably shouldn't be a class member in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. yes, this isnt a real life situation

Comment: while this answer is more practical, Im accepting the asnwer by @pepijn-kramer since it is more relevant to the question asked. Thanks again